# Saving file in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: file-permissions

I am trying to make some changes in etc/environment file and when I am going to save the file it shows like this,

"you don't have the permissions necessary to save the file"

please help me how can I change the file permission in Ubuntu.

Thanks,
Abhilash

Answer (score 0):

You need to open the file with command `sudo` at the beginning. You will be then prompted for the root password. After writing it, open editor will open, and you will be able to save file.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where you try to open the file. If are you terminal, you can run sudo nano /etc/environment (or any other editor, e.g. vim etc). You will need to enter the root password. The editor opens (in this case nano), make changes to it, then press Ctrl+O, press Enter, then Ctrl+X.

If you want to open it with gedit or any other GUI editor you need to install gksu: run in terminal `sudo apt-get install gksu`. You will asked for your root password, type it in and the application will be installed. Then you can run gedit in the terminal like this: `gksudo gedit /etc/environment`. Make the changes and press Save as in Windows Notepad.